# Как можно реализовать вывод ошибок по выбранным id

Tags: php

После отправки я получаю 2 массива

1  `Array ( [order_id] => Array ( [0] => 48 [1] => 47 ) )` id заказа которые были выбраны

2 `Array ( [error] => Array ( [0] => 206 [1] => 206 ) )` ошибки

view

```
 <?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>
<tr>
   <td><?php echo $order['order_id'];?></td> // здесь список всех id коотрые есть
   <td></td> // здесь вывести ошибку тех id которые были выбраны
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: <?= implode(', ', $order['order_id']); ?> вместо <?php echo $order['order_id'];?>, и соответственно <?= implode(', ', $order['error']); ?>

Comment: `<?php echo $order['order_id'];?>` это список всех `id` которые есть в базе, $orders это данные которые я вывожу с базы, а эти два массива я получаю, после отправки, и мне нужно вывести напротив выбранных  `id` полученные ошибки, мне по идеи нужно как то сравнить id и если такой `id` есть тогда показывать ошибку,

Comment: В массиве [error] значения элементов должны соответствовать значениям элементов в массиве [order_id]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим после отправки мы получаем два массива $inputArray и $errorArray, если я правильно понял условия и задачу, то будет примерно так.

```
<?php foreach ($orders as $order){
    $key = array_search($order['order_id'], $inputArray);
    if ($key !== false): ?>
    <tr>
         <td><?= $order['order_id'];?></td> 
         <td><?= $errorArray[$key]?></td> 
    </tr>
<?php endif; } ?>
```

Comment: Это то что нужно, огромное спасибо за помощь